# Можно ли получить текущий размер фоновой картинки(background-image)?

Tags: javascript, css

Для расчёта скорости движения фона при скролле хочу получить высоту картинки `background-image` по факту её подстройки под ширину блока.
Стиль фона такой:

```
{
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center top;
}
```

При скролле будет меняться вертикальная координата `background-position`, со скоростью, рассчитанной на основании отношения высот фона и блока.
Это вообще здоровая мысль, или лучше положить картинку в `img` и двигать его?

Comment: "по факту её подстройки под ширину блока" - вот тут не ясно, оригинальный размер изображения или же блока, в котором оное есть бекграунд?

Comment: Хоть `background-image` хоть `img` ты высоту  каритинки не получишь, только высоту блока

Comment: Без понимания как бекграунд спозиционирован и все такое, сложно дать однозначно верный ответ ... размер исходника узнать получив её `src` и дальше что-то типа `const img = new Image(); img.src = src; console.log(img.height);` ... дальше можно из каких-то формул и расчетов исходя из свойств бекграунда высчитать какова "степень деформации" ... ну и все в этом духе.

Comment: @Kirill Korushki Именно фонового изображения и именно по факту подстройки. Не блок и не оригинал.

Comment: @MedvedevDev то есть всё от исходных данных только?
Сейчас дополню вопрос.

Comment: @AleksandrShemetillo, да, узнать реальный размер, а не исходный без доп. вычислений не выйдет (на сколько я знаю).

Comment: [На англоязычном SO был подобный вопрос.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688747/how-to-get-the-current-real-background-image-size-when-background-size-is-c)

Comment: @Air у img есть naturalHeight

Comment: @andreymal,  Я в курсе я подумал он оригинальный размер  именно картинки хочет,  а `naturalHeight`, на сколько я знаю отдает высоту `img`

Comment: @Air нет, высоту img отдаёт height, а naturalHeight отдаёт оригинальный размер картинки

Comment: @andreymal, благодарю, буду знать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот вам готовое решение:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wHeight = $(window).height();

  function parallax() {
    var pHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
    var pMiddle = pHeight / 2;
    var wMiddle = wHeight / 2;
    var fromTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    var speed = $(this).attr('data-parallax-speed');
    var rangeA = (fromTop - wHeight);
    var rangeB = (fromTop + pHeight);
    var rangeC = (fromTop - wHeight);
    var rangeD = (pMiddle + fromTop) - (wMiddle + (wMiddle / 2));

    if (rangeA < 0) {
      rangeA = 0;
      rangeB = wHeight
    }

    var percent = (scrolled - rangeA) / (rangeB - rangeA);
    percent = percent * 100;
    percent = percent * speed;
    percent = percent.toFixed(2);

    var animFromBottom = (scrolled - rangeC) / (rangeD - rangeC);
    animFromBottom = animFromBottom.toFixed(2);

    if (animFromBottom >= 1) {
      animFromBottom = 1;
    }

    $(this).css('background-position', 'center ' + percent + '%');
  }
  $('.parallax').each(parallax);
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    $('.parallax').each(parallax);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 70vh;
}

.img {
  background: url(https://i.dmarge.com/2015/02/new-in-box_1.jpg) no-repeat center / cover;
}

.img2 {
  min-height: 300px;
  background: url(http://lmlnews.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/2014-11-02_165540.jpg) no-repeat center / cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img2 parallax" data-parallax-speed="-1"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="img parallax" data-parallax-speed="1"></div>
<div></div>
```

Если я ошибся с необходимостью достижения конечного результата, то из JS вы без труда найдете все необходимые участки по определению высот и иных координат.

Comment: Благодарю. Обходит проблему получения размеров. Я только скорость исключил для себя, поскольку любой показатель кроме единицы даёт либо недокрутку, либо, что хуже, возможность выхода фона за край блока.
Непонятно, как быть с ответом )
Проблему исходную решает, но на вопрос в его формулировке не отвечает...

Comment: На самом деле, если вы попробуете разные варианты изменения высоты блока, то увидите, что фон не выходит за его пределы с параметром cover. Однако, если высота блока будет соответствовать высоте изображения, то прокрутка не будет осуществляться. Когда-то и я искал легкий универсальный вариант parallax, но их не существует. Либо фон сильно будет "резать", либо какой-то такой вариант, как в примере. Для меня его вполне достаточно.

Comment: В порядке самообучения переписал ваш пример под плагин jQuery. Так его можно использовать в цепочке и он сразу применяется ко всему набору. https://jsfiddle.net/sapolio/cauhoqam/
Не очень наивно? )

Comment: @AleksandrShemetillo стало немного аккуратней. Правда вы зря исключили скорость перемещения. Если блок с parallax находится вверху, что довольно часто бывает, установив отрицательное значение в `data-parallax-speed` фон начнет подыматься медленней остального содержимого. Добавил в пример нужный участок.

Comment: А в какой пример? ))

Comment: @AleksandrShemetillo в примере который вы видите выше)

Comment: А там ничего не изменилось. Видимо, нужна ссылка на форк.

Comment: @AleksandrShemetillo я добавил блок с отрицательным значением смещение фона, что замедляет его ход по отношению к остальному контенту. Просто запустите пример.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myBlock = document.getElementById('myblock');

style = myBlock.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(myBlock, false),
  bg_url = style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2').split(',')[0];

var image = new Image();
image.src = bg_url;

console.log('width  : ' + image.width);
console.log('height : ' + image.height);
```

```css
#myblock {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-image: url("http://blog.trueclothing.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Rasta_Homer_by_djog.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="myblock"></div>
```

[спасибо сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655367/why-does-elem-style-backgroundimage-return-empty-rather-than-the-css-property)

Comment: похоже, не работает. Возвращается размер оригинала. Вот, применил к своей ситуации:
https://jsfiddle.net/ke8rh71u/1/